# Как в одной ячейке grid'a вывести 2 даты с разделителем?

Tags: java, дата, gwt, grid

Мне необходимо при выводе информации из бд в одной ячейке таблицы grid выводить 2 даты в формате

```
dd.MM.yyyy-dd.MM.yyyy
```

Первая дата берется из одного поля класса, другая, соответственно, из другого.

[image]

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! здесь принято в одном вопросе задавать один вопрос. а второй, третий, и последующие — задавать с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос очень размытый, но в первом приближении решение (за исключением названий и методов полей для дат) выглядит вот так:

```
....
dataGrid.addColumn(new TextColumn<DbType>
  {
   public String getValue(DbType dbType)
    {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"); 
    return sdf.format(dbType.getDate1())+"-"+sdf.format(dbType.getDate2());
    } 
  }
);
```